# My mockito spy method is not working. Type mismatch Error

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

Using `mockito` for the first time and spy doesn't seem to be working, and gives an error when I try to use it.

I am using `mockito-core version 2.7.22`, but I have also tried `version 3.3.0` and the problem persists.

Here is some psuedocode example. I am testing a method in ClassA:

```
public class ClassATest{

    private ClassA classAMock;

    private ClassB classBMock;

    private ClassC classCMock;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ClassBMock = Mockito.mock(ClassB.class);
        ClassCMock = Mockito.mock(ClassC.class);

        ClassAMock = Mockito.spy(ClassA.class);

    }
```

The .spy line gives an error that says:

> Type Mismatch. Cannot convert from Class >ClassA< to ClassA.

`.mock`works fine.

> Recommends 1 fix: Add cast to 'ClassA'.

This happens to all classes that I try to spy, not just `ClassA`.

I also know that if I use the `@Spy Annotation` instead, I get no errors, but the mocking outright fails to mock, like my 'when' methods run the real methods instead of the mocked ones.

My mockito imports are:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
```

EDIT: 
Adding the class hierarchy...

```
public class ClassA{}
public class ClassB{}
public class ClassC{}
```

If anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This example works for me:

```java
public class ClassATest {

    private ClassA classAMock;
    private ClassB classBMock;
    private ClassC classCMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        classAMock = Mockito.spy(ClassA.class);
        classBMock = Mockito.mock(ClassB.class);
        classCMock = Mockito.mock(ClassC.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(classAMock.getClass());
    }

    public static class ClassA {}
    public static class ClassB {}
    public static class ClassC {}
}
```

If it also does on your side, maybe you have a starting point and you could advance it until the problem occurs.

Comment: Sorry, I have since edited my original post - the JsonToAvro should not even be included here. It should read


classAMock = Mockito.spy(ClassA.class).



The class hierarchy is pretty simple:

public class ClassA {}
public class ClassB {}
public class ClassC {}

Comment: Thanks for the update, i updated my answer as well.